# n-fold numerical integration error

Tags: numerical-integration, computational-geometry

I'm trying to evaluate the volume of cut-off simplex, which is
$x_i\geq 0$ for all $i\leq n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_k\leq\alpha_k$ for all $k$.
And there is a restriction $0<\alpha_1\leq\cdots\leq\alpha_n=1$.
Note that $n$ can be varied and I code with Module.
Here is my implementation:

```
prob[alpha_] := Module[{xvars, range, expression}, 
    xvars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[alpha]}];
    range = Table[{xvars[[i]], 0, alpha[[i]] - Sum[xvars[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}]}, {i, 1, Length[alpha]}];
    expression = Factorial[Length[alpha]];
    NIntegrate[expression, Sequence@@range]];
```

If I run this code with alpha={1}, then the error "NIntegrate: Invalid variable or limit(s) in {x1,0,1}" comes. It I detached "N" from NIntegrate, then it normally runs well. Of course, if I don't use Module, such as

```
 NIntegrate[1, {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1 - x1}]
```

It also really runs well. I want to find the "fast" evaluation of this cut-off simplex. How can I fix this code to run NIntegrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NIntegrate` has attribute `HoldAll`, thus, you have to enforce evaluation, e.g., with `Evaluate`

```
prob[alpha_] := 
  Module[{xvars, range, expression}, 
   xvars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, Length[alpha]}];
   range = Table[{xvars[[i]], 0, alpha[[i]] - Sum[xvars[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}]}, {i, 1, Length[alpha]}];
   expression = Factorial[Length[alpha]];
   NIntegrate[expression, Evaluate[Sequence @@ range]]
   ];
```

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!